# Loopback giving Maximum call stack size exceeded error

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs

I have set up my Loopback project and installed other packages required to run my project. Whenever I tried to run the application with the command within the folder

```
    node .
```

it is raising following error:

```
test_app/node_modules/strong-remoting/lib/shared-method.js:157
  if (/^prototype\./.test(name)) {
                     ^

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

I am literally unknown about this error. Can you please suggest any solution?

Comment: Can you share your code where it gives to you error

Comment: @FerhatBAŞ, I haven't written a single line of code. Just created model and trying to set relation in the models using loopback. When I try to rerun the application with `node .` it is giving this error.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had the same issue and this worked for me:

1. Go in your models folder which should be somewhere --> /projectfolder/common/models/
2. Open the files of the models you just set your relation about --> yourmodel.json
3. Delete this part in your "relations" -->

   ```
    "options": {
      "nestRemoting": true
    }
   ```
4. If you have set 2 relations such as hasMany and belongesTo you should apply this to booth.

Comment: You are the life saver!. Thanks buddy!.

Comment: The question should be, what effect will deleting this option have on your API. This option was chosen for a reason